# Become an independent math researcher.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algorithms, self-learning, computational-geometry

I'm 22 years old and studied 2 years of math before droping out to travel the world as an assistant of a friend who make commercials, documentaries and media creation in general.

I really love math and cs however I love to travel and learn about new cultures, so I can't go back to school in the near future, I'm getting more responsibilities and probably continue doing something similar for living like photography or videography.

I was wondering is possible to become an amateur mathematician doing relevant research independently? I can study 4 hr everyday, no more because of my work  and because I have many hobbies. Also I can't work intellectually in a subject for more than 4 hrs. (I use to practice shogi and learn that 4 hrs distributed in a day work best for me).

I've liked algorithms since I'm a child,  When I was in elementary school  I liked this girl but I was super shy so I thought that if everybody in the class submit an ordered list of the people who liked we could make an algorithm to match people. I develop an algorithm who would make this possible and I remember that not was that simple, almost took me a whole year.

I think I have strong basics in abstract algebra, real analysis and linear algebra. I also have self study algorithms, computer complexity, basic computer theory and basic computational geometry. But now I don't know how to keep going. I also know to program because I enjoy making programs to solve problems like python scripts to automate download series or to automate the things I repeat a lot. For the things I learn I probably could get a CS degree since I'm interested in this themes since I was 12 and took one robotics course, I didn't learn much robotics but I was amazed with computers so I started programming.

I'm not interested in money, positions in universities or even social prestige (I probably would use TrashPanda as my penName like the boubarky school of math). Because I think academia has some big problems like the way academical publishing works. But as you probably has noted I really like fake internet prestige and I think don't would be cool that someone with no formal math education and with a pen name like trash panda started to publish in academic publications.

I admire profundy Erick Demaine and I after "reading"(I couldn't comprenhend many of the paper he have) some of his papers and the page in the CSAIL of MIT  I think I'm interested in:

​

- Discrete and computational geometry: [Folding and unfolding](http://erikdemaine.org/folding/), [linkages](http://erikdemaine.org/linkage/), robotics, motion planning, dissections, [simple polygonizations](http://erikdemaine.org/polygonization/)
- Algorithms and their analysis: Adaptive computation, graph algorithms,  string matching, randomized algorithms, approximation algorithms,  fixed-parameter algorithms, streaming algorithms
- Combinatorics: Discrete mathematics, graph theory (matchings, minors, treewidth, …), [combinatorial game theory](http://erikdemaine.org/games/) .

​

My plan is to self learn combinatorics (With the books:  [*Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810211392) by Chen Chuan Chong and Brualdis book in combinatorics). Dominate the book CLRS of algorithm analysis. For CG I plan to complete Devadoss & O'Rourke's Discrete  & Computational Geometry (I'm half way), the Springer published Computational  Geometry: Algorithms and Applications, and David Mount's notes ([Page on Umd](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/754/Lects/754lects.pdf)) .

But I figurated that I can start reading some papers that are not that hard, I pass a lot of time in Mexico and in Chile so probably I can look from a professor there that could help me.

Or maybe someone here would like to mentor me. (I promise that I could research a lot here or in mathexchange before as you)

What you guys recommend? I feel like when you like a person so much but you can't see her/him.

Is there some papers I should read? How can I discover a proper theme acording my current level to try to investigate?

Thanks in advance to everybody and obligatory sfmbe.

Comment: $4$ hours a day usually isn't enough to make much progress, to be honest.

Comment: I don't want to be discouraging, but it can be difficult to pursue "serious" research outside of academia for a large number of reasons. Most notably, you don't have other people actively researching around you, so you're missing out on great conversations, which help solve problems. Plus, when research isn't (at least part of) your job, it can be really easy to put it off, much like practicing an instrument.

Comment: That said, there have been exceptions before, and if you're willing to put the time in, Combinatorics is a really rich field, with a lot of problems that are fairly simple to understand, which makes them fairly accessible for anyone with the time and the desire to think about them. If you can find a real-life mentor, or even a friend who is also willing to put the time in to work on some problems, it would help greatly. And remember, math can be fun for its own sake! There are hundreds of "amateur" mathematicians, and even if their work isn't game-changing, they still love the work they do ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor completely agree. Also, I think that doing research in fields like CS is a lot more doable part-time, and can be math focused. (Also, you made me remember how I've forgotten to play violin in 3 years. Yikes)

Comment: Also, parts of this post read like college application essays.

Comment: If You plan to be self - employed or have Your own business in the field, I think it is an open door. If You plan to work for someone else, I think You can do Your own research and look for certification somehow (for engineer this is possible, idk for Maths). This is assuming You are very passionate about maths and CS that they can make You forget time (sometimes I did not realize it was already 3am while grinding combinatorics for example).

Comment: Leopoldo Nachbin (Brazilian mathematician), once said: *In order to do mathematics, it is needed to be in the right place, with the right people, at the right moment and still be lucky*. ([Source](http://adonaisantanna.blogspot.com/2015/02/como-seguir-uma-carreira-de-pesquisador.html), in Portugese.) Therefore, if he is right, it is not easy (if possible) to become an "independet researcher". Maybe, you will have to be an exception.

Comment: Yeah, is because I like it and I one think that convince me to pursue this is that Erick Demaine was he become a tetris grandmaster when he prove that Tetris is NP hard problem. I don't agree that 4 hrs is not enough time to advance considerable in something. Just imagine how many time people in academy deal with burocracy and other stuff. Also when I was younger I become really proficient in classical guitar just practicing 3 hr each day. And I think it was Ana vidovic who said that is better to study 4 hrs in absoluty concentration.

Comment: Maybe I used badly the term independent, I think that alone you can do very little in almost anything and that talking with the right people is vital to learn and to progress, but I think that this maybe is now possible like for example how many people from all around the world reduce the cota for the twins numbers. @HallaSurvivor how can I get in a comunity of this "amateur" mathematicians?

Comment: @Pedro, but with the technology I think is easier to comunicate with people from all around the world. Like in a conference call, or sharing a whiteboard with a graphic tablet or similar. Also I probably could visit people from Mexico or Chile since there is where we do most of our work.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I don't plan to work in math, CS or even need to work, my dad have enough money so neither me or my 2 sisters have to worry about anything. So I follow my passions. Forgeting time or to eat happens a lot to me, when I try to solve a math problem, when programming or when I play the guitar and I'm stuck in a phrase, or watching movies.

Comment: The problem of being *one amateur working 4 hrs* is that, maybe, you will have to compete with a *group of professionals working 12 hrs* in the same problem. If you is not the first, you don't gain the credit. But you are rigth, probably it is possible to make progress if you comunicate with the right people.

Comment: @Pedro I didn't know researchers worked that hard. That's really amazing. I don't really care about getting credit. I plan to put all my ideas in a public github repositorie or somewhere many people could access with ease. For me is not a competition is to learn more about math, computers and don't get bored. I really love math or in general thinks that are hard, I don't really like to be unchallenge.

Comment: The mathematician Hardy reported doing 4 hours of math per day (in A Mathematician's Apology). The book The Mathematician's Survival Guide says that if you can do 5-6 hours of focused work, 5-6 days a week, then you're doing good. I think 4 hours per day is fine. Just go deep in an area you're interested in. (As has been mentioned, your progress will be much faster and probability of success higher if you happen to have friends who are great at math and you can absorb their knowledge.)

Comment: @littleO agree. Also Ana Vidovic a amazing guitar player said something similar focus is the secret.

Comment: That said, you certainly seem far more diligent and disciplined at your age and earlier than I ever was, and certainly much more attuned to possibilities and sources of inspiration, not limitations and barriers (helped by my own relative economic privation and other isolation). So you definitely have way more capacity to pull this off and I think you can do it - I'm lost goods now at 29 years old with less than half of what you have. The most important resource - which I wish I learned 15-20 years ago - that you have is diligence and consistent focus. Never underestimate that: you don't know

Comment: the lacker side.

Comment: I would thus suggest you should look at the total range of topics covered by a general research level Maths curriculum and get them down. I want to say, though - a lot (too many) of texts really don't do as good a job as they could at explaining things and expect one to just "get it", which means that that time is not spent as efficiently as it could be. Just as a warning.

Comment: I think it's hard to be a good mathematician working independently but it's necessary to work independently to be an excellent mathematician

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to do is not necessarily impossible, but it is unlikely, and harder than you think.

First of all, you seem to underestimate what it takes to become a researcher. There is no uniform rule, as there are wildly different levels of talent, and also different areas require different levels of expertise to be able to produce research. That said, a mathematician typically requires (in North America, but things are mostly equivalent elsewhere), to be at the stage of being an independent researcher,

- A 4-year B.Sc. honours, followed by
- a 2-year M.Sc., followed by
- a 4-year Ph.D., followed by
- One or two postdocs, maybe 2 years each.

From what you mention, you sound like you are at about half-way through the first step.
During most of the above-mentioned periods, a normal person would be devoting more than 4 hours per day to their math.

Besides the great amount of hours required, these are not just "study time". There is a whole maturation process, where new notions and ideas become natural and one can use them with ease at the next level. Eventually, exposure to research comes in the form of reading papers, but also attending seminars and conferences, receiving feedback on one's own talks and classes, and one-on-one talk with other fellow mathematicians. Avoiding all of these would make it a lot harder to get to be thinking math at a research level. And, more importantly, it would be really hard to get to know what problems the community is interested in.

In summary, you can study as much math as you want on your own, but if you care for whatever you do to be appreciated by others, it is unlikely that it will happen without interaction with the math community. And this might be hard, even if you are working seriously: every mathematician is familiar with "cranks" who write at them or try to engage at conferences to convince them that their "research" is great. It (almost) never is, so there is a strong tendency to dismiss people from outside the academic world.

Comment: Agree entirely but how can I get in touch with the math community. I travel almost all year and never stay more than 2 or 3 months in a place. Actually that was my question. Seems I explain it badly. What I mean as independet is that I don't work at a school.

Comment: I don't really have a solution for you, I was just explaining how things usually work. Over those many years of masters, doctorate, and postdoc, prospective mathematicians get to know many colleagues and later use those contacts in their careers. It may be possible afterwards to more or less have a career via remote communication, but it will be super hard to establish one to start with.

Comment: Precisely math.stackexchange.com and mathoverflow.net are the places where you can begin to get the feeling of what is relevant and what is not. It is as good as it gets about interacting with mathematicians. Said this, I fully agree with @MartinArgerami, not impossible, but in practice highly unlikely